# bindValue inside loop for DELETE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'little' problem with my method for DELETE query. 
This code doesn't give any error, so it should work. But nothing is changed inside database, row that I want to delete is still there.

The main problem is probably here:

```
$query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

            foreach ($value as $row) {
                if(is_int($row)){
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$field[$k].'', $row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                } else
                {
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$field[$k].'', $row, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
                $k++;
            }
        $query->execute();
```

Something is wrong inside that loop. My prepared SQL looks like: 
DELETE FROM account WHERE id = ':id'
So it looks fine, and I am simply trying to bind values for :id (and if there will be more WHEREs it will bind them too) but nothing happens. No errors and no effects. 
I checked foreach manually, $field[$k] and $row returns correct values. 
I am sitting on it 4 hours. No clue what's wrong... or I am just blind.

Also I am using exactly the same loop inside my Insert method, and there everything works.

My code: (sry for long code)

```
class Delete extends Connection{

public function deleteClause($table, $where = array()){

    if (count($where) % 3 === 0) {


            $length = count($where) / 3;

            $counter = $count = $k = 0;


            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {


                for ($j = $count; $j < (count($where) / $length) + $count; $j++) {
                    $field[$i]    = $where[$j];
                    $j            = $j + 1;
                    $operator[$i] = $where[$j];
                    $j            = $j + 1;
                    $value[$i]    = $where[$j];
                    $counter      = $j + 1;
                }
                $count = $counter;
            }

            $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE ";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                if ($i == $length - 1) {
                    $sql .= "$field[$i] $operator[$i] ':$field[$i]'";
                } else {
                    $sql .= "$field[$i] $operator[$i] ':$field[$i]' AND ";
                }
            }
            echo $sql;
            $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);


            foreach ($value as $row) {
                if(is_int($row)){
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$field[$k].'', $row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                } else
                {
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$field[$k].'', $row, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
                $k++;
            }
            $query->execute();

        return true;
    } else {
        echo "Niepoprawna ilość argumentów funkcji";
        return false;
    }        
}}
```

Comment: pdo function `errorInfo()` will help you to find your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using placeholders, in your prepared queries there's no use for `'`.
Lines like

```
$sql .= "$field[$i] $operator[$i] ':$field[$i]'"
```

should be rewritten to

```
$sql .= "$field[$i] $operator[$i] :$field[$i]"
```

No quotes around placeholders - `:$field[$i]`, not `':$field[$i]'`.

Comment: OH MY GOD, thank you ! I wish I could upvote your answer, but I'm still newbie here and I can't. Thank you ;)